# How to arrange radio buttons in certain way

Tags: android, android-layout

If  I have a radiogroup with 7 radiobuttons and I want them to be aligned like that:

```
           button2    button5
button1    button3    button6
           button4    button7
```

Is there a way  I can do the above with one RadioGroup (I am ok with even button1 being on first line but this is the general layout I am looking for)

Please help

Thanks

Comment: How Can you use a relative layout with ONE radio Group?

Comment: Sorry, yes of course I missed the group bit.  Since it's based on a LinearLayout, you might be out of luck.  Perhaps drop the group and handle the selection logic yourself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could implement your own button handling logic, based on this http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener.html:

```
public class RadioButtonHandler implements RadioButton.OnCheckedChangeListener {

    private CompoundButton currentlyCheckedButton = null;

    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton button, boolean isChecked) {
            if (isChecked) {
               currentlyCheckedButton .setChecked(false);
               currentlyCheckedButton = button;
            }
    }

    public void addButton(RadioButton button) {
           // if this is the first button, set it as the current button
           if (currentlyCheckedButton == null) {
               currentlyCheckedButton = button;
           }
           button.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
    }

    public CompoundButton getCheckedRadioButton() {
        return currentlyCheckedButton ;
    } 
}
```

Instantiate this class and call addButton for each button that the class should control.  Then you can layout your buttons in whatever view group you need.  Add extra logic to the onCheckChanged callback or call getCheckedRadioButton which will return a reference to the currently checked button.

[EDIT]  Fixed typo = getCheckedButton -> getCheckedRadioButton